# How to add a dropdown menu on clicking the button in jsp?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form with two buttons one should submit the form and other should add a dropdown menu each time I click it.(If I click it two times two dropdowns should appear).
Here is my form:

```
<form name="form1" action="anotherfile.jsp">
 <input type="text" name="box1">
 <input type="text" name="box2">
 <input type="submit" name="Add_dropdown">     
 <input type="submit" name="Submit_form">          
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should work:

```
<form name="form1" action="anotherfile.jsp">
<input type="text" name="box1">
<input type="text" name="box2">
<input type="button" id="add_dd">
<span id="cont"></span>
<input type="submit" name="Submit_form">
</form>
<script>
ddBtn = document.getElementById("add_dd");
ddBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
c = document.getElementById("cont");
dd = "<select name='dd'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
c.innerHTML += dd;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks..although I didn't use it but still the solution was appreciable.